# Combine log files into 1 great report using a bash script/command

Tags: linux, bash

I've got 3 (or more) log files and I wish to create a combined log report when the output of each file is in a different column.

Example:

```
$ cat log1

test1
1
1
1

$ cat log2

test2
2
2
2
```

What I'm looking for is a way to create the below report into a new log file:

```
test1 test2
1     2
1     2
1     2
```

Comment: Do you know hte [`paste`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?paste) command?

Comment: now i know! thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `paste`

```
$ paste log1 log2
test1   test2
1       2
1       2
1       2
```

From `man page`

```
   paste - merge lines of files

   Write  lines  consisting  of  the sequentially corresponding lines from each FILE, separated by TABs, to standard output.  With no FILE, or when
   FILE is -, read standard input.
```

**EDIT**

When there are more lines in file2

```
$ cat log1
test1
1
1
1

$ cat log2
test2
2
2
2
2
2
2

$ paste log1 log2
test1   test2
1       2
1       2
1       2
        2
        2
        2
```

Comment: Well, I had to choose 1. sputnick was first with the answer, but nu11 was credited for the time it took to edit `:)`

Comment: what if i've got more values in the 2nd file (i.e. four "2") and i would like to keep them all under the same column?

Comment: @Nadav Paste will do that for you as well. I have edited my answer. Hope it helps you

Comment: mmm for some reason the output is not aligned correctly :-( maybe since I've got few texts inside the log files and not just one character

Comment: @Nadav It should work if it contains more characters. It may not give a neat output if the entire line does not fit in single line

Comment: cat log1
Thu Dec  4 09:25:04 IST 2014
Thu Dec  4 09:25:04 IST 2014
cat log2 
Thu Dec  4 09:25:04 IST 2014
Thu Dec  4 09:25:04 IST 2014

Thu Dec  4 09:25:04 IST 2014

paste log1 log2
Thu Dec  4 09:25:04 IST 2014 Thu Dec  4 09:25:04 IST 2014
Thu Dec  4 09:25:04 IST 2014 Thu Dec  4 09:25:04 IST 2014
 
 Thu Dec  4 09:25:04 IST 2014

Comment: @Nadav The alignment problem is because, paste adds a tab as delimitter between the lines where as the lines in first file are longer than a single tab

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
paste file1 file2
```